# вытаскивание данных с html разметки и передача в модель asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Идет загрузка новостей из базы данных: я загружаю список с объектами и выгружаю в html.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <article>
        <div class="Title">
            @{
                if (item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId().AsInt())
                {
                  <input type="submit" id=@item.Id value="Delete" />
                }
            }
            <span>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="NewsInformation">
            <div class="NameUser">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Login)
            </div>
            <div class="CreationDate">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
}
```

Если айди пользователя, который создал новость соответствует айди пользователя в объекте новости то мы добавляем элемент-кнопку, при нажатии на которую, пользователь должен удалить новость. Возник вопрос - загрузить список новостей - всё ок, а от узнать, какую новость удалять с базы данных - не известно как реализовать.

Comment: И что в итоге вам непонятно? Вы не знаете как сформулировать условие, по которому будет выводиться кнопка удаления или не знаете собственно кнопку нарисовать? Или не понимаете как написать экшн в котором получить запись по ID новости и грохнуть её?

Comment: Не знаю как написать экшн в котором нужно узнать айди и убить его в бдхе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, обычно так не делается.

Допустим, у вас есть некоторый NewsController, в котором есть All:

```
public class NewsController : ProjectnameBaseController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> All()
    {
        var news = await this.Db.News.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();

        var model = new NewsAllModel
        {
            News = news,
        };

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

И во вью вы делаете напротив каждой новости форму для удаления (ссылка хуже – GET неидемпотентный , плюс нельзя токены ставить)

```
@using Projectname.WebUI.Models.NewsViewModels
@model NewsAllModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Все новости";
}

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>

@if (Model.News.Length > 0)
{
    <div class="list-group">
        @foreach (var News in Model.News)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Action("Detailed", "News", new NewsDetailedModel {NewsID = News.ID})" class="list-group-item">@News.Name</a>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "NewsController ", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" title="delete news">Delete</button>
            }

        }
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>В базе нет ни одной новости.</p>
}
```

Ну и в NewsController у вас будет какой-то простенький экшн в котором по ID новости вы его удалите из базы.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: Сделал так                                                                                                                             @if (item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId().AsInt())
                    {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                        }
                    }
                Но Delete(int id) не принимает никаких чисел